Is it possible to build a Flatpak package using flatpak-builder without FUSE?
I'm trying to build a Flatpak package with flatpak-builder in an environment where I don't have access to FUSE. This leads to the following problem:
Initializing build dir
Committing stage init to cache
Starting build of com.example.TestApp
fuse: device not found, try 'modprobe fuse' first
========================================================================
Building module poetry-deps in /opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/.flatpak-builder/build/poetry-deps-1
========================================================================
Running: pip3 install --no-index --find-links="file://${PWD}" --prefix=${FLATPAK_DEST} altgraph attrdict3 bidict certifi charset-normalizer contourpy cycler fonttools idna importlib-resources kiwisolver macholib matplotlib mypy mypy-extensions numpy packaging pefile pillow pyinstaller pyinstaller-hooks-contrib pyparsing pyserial python-dateutil python-vxi11 pyvisa pyvisa-py pywin32-ctypes readerwriterlock requests scipy setuptools six tomli types-pyserial types-wxpython typing-extensions urllib3 watchdog wxpython wxPython wxPython wxPython wxPython zipp
error: Build directory /opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/.flatpak-builder/rofiles/rofiles-WlL1EH not initialized, use flatpak build-init
Error: module poetry-deps: Child process exited with code 1

Is there any way I can work around this? Getting access to FUSE is not an option as it is a limited environment on hardware I don't control.

You can work around this by giving flatpak-builder the --disable-rofiles-fuse argument. For example:
$ flatpak-builder build com.example.TestApp.json --disable-rofiles-fuse

